# How to run rspec tests in different configurations

Tags: ruby, rspec, automated-tests

*My problem must have been already solved but I can't find it.*

I have tests/examples in various describe blocks, in different files. These tests can run in three different configurations phone, tablet and desktop. What is the best practice to group by tests so that I can run them together or standalone.

I tried following [shared_example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group) approach

```
shared_examples 'tests' do |form_factor|
   it 'example 1' do 
   end
   it 'example 2' do 
   end
   it 'example 3' do 
   end
end
```

in another file

```
 shared_examples 'tests' do |form_factor|
    it 'example 1' do 
    end
    it 'example 2' do 
    end
 end
```

But this approach does not work with tests in another file. As soon as I add another shared_examples block in another file I get

```
WARNING: Shared example group 'tests' has been previously defined at:
  /1_spec.rb:3
...and you are now defining it at:
  /2_spec.rb:2
The new definition will overwrite the original one.
```

I also tried the approach of going with environment variables but passing all these on command line like this

```
FORM_FACTOR=phone rspec .
FORM_FACTOR=table rspec .
```

seems unwieldy. Suggestions? My objective is to be able to pass in different form_factors or run all of them. So if I do something like

> rspec run_all

all  the form factors should be passed and run all three tests
and if I send in

> rspec run_phone

only phone should be send in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is a combination of RSpec [`shared_examples`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) and tags.

I'll show a very slimmed down example:

```
shared_examples "testable device" do |form_factor|
  it "example 1" do
  end
  it "example 2" do
  end
end

context "with a tablet", type: :tablet do
  let(:configuration) { }
  it_behaves_like "testable device", "700x800"
end

context "with a phone", type: :phone do
  let(:configuration) { }
  it_behaves_like "testable device", "300x400"
end
```

With no additional configuration, if you want to just run all of the types, you run `rspec` as normal. If you want only a specific type, `rspec --tag type:phone`.

If you use these configurations across multiple files, I suggest checking out: [`shared_context`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-context)

```
shared_context "tablet configuration", type: :tablet do
  before { @some_var = :some_value }

  def shared_method
    "it works"
  end

  let(:configuration) { {'arbitrary' => 'object'} }
end
```

By default, if you provide metadata to the `shared_context` definition, the context will automatically be included in specs with matching metadata.

Answer (score 6):

Add in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file custom configuration for different filters:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  if config.filter[:type] == :desktop
    # configuration for desktop
  elsif config.filter[:type] == :tablet
    # configuration for tablet
  end
  ....
end
```

Yes you will still have to run separate command for each type, but why not concatenate them into one:

```
rspec --tag type:desktop; rspec --tag type:tablet; rspec --tag type:phone
```

Another option would be create Rake task that will run rspec tests for each type.

Comment: good idea.. hoping to see something better though because our CI system wouldn't like this.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using [tags](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option)?:

```
describe "a test", :phone do
  ...
end

describe "another test", :tablet do
  ..
end

$ rspec --tag phone # runs examples/groups tagged :phone

describe "yet another test", :type => :desktop do
  ...
end

$ rspec --tag type:desktop  # runs examples/groups tagged :desktop
```

Comment: But my tests are all same, I just need to be able to send them different configurations. Even if I use the type: desktop approach I will loose the ability to run all configurations with single command.

Comment: Did you ever achieve this? Thanks